# Using two alias together

Tags: linux, ubuntu, alias

I have set an alias for sudo (please) and an alias for apt-get (quickly)
As long as I use both of them not together the commands work. `please shutdown now` or `quickly install vim` As soon as I start using both of them `please quickly install vim` I get the error

> sudo: quickly: command not found

I tried to make an alias for both of them `alias "please quickly "="sudo apt-get"`, but that does also not work.

Comment: Maybe edit the f word into something else... Just for the sake of asking the question...

Comment: I also did think my Ubuntu may have feelings and doesnt want to hear bad words, so I changed it to quickly, but still same error...

Comment: **What shell?** [Solution for Bash](https://superuser.com/q/712366/432690).

Comment: Used bash, thanks a lot for the link, solved my problem!

Comment: **Moderator Warning** - please do not use obscenities in your posts. I've removed it for you. Note that other users may have flagged your post as "rude or abusive" leading to possible rep loss or suspension. Please read [Be Nice](https://superuser.com/help/be-nice): "Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive"